# Query to execute value from column in table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table with sql as the column value In one of the colum. I need to run that sql and need to save the result in next colum in the table.

Eg

```
Column1 column2 column3 column4
1 , table1 , select count(*), count(distinct id) from table 1
2 , table2 , select count(*), count (distinct phoneno) from table 2
```

I need to display the query result in column 4 in impala or hive table will this be possible,

Comment: You cannot really do this inside the database.  It requires dynamic SQL, which is most easily accomplished at the application layer.

Comment: @syed. No with Hive but I did similar thing in spark. you may need to build some logic to create and execute queries dynamically. may this help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315590/pythonspark-need-to-execute-hive-queries-from-file-columns/57321048#57321048